# ERROR: could not connect to the publisher: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I am trying to create a logical replication between 2 postgres servers. 
But when I try to create a subscription from the slave to the master I get the error

ERROR:  could not connect to the publisher: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host

Here are my configs.

Master server ip 192.168.100.21;
Slave server ip 192.168.100.22

Master server pg_hba.conf :

host  replication  replicate  192.168.100.22/32   md5

Slave server pg_hba.conf :

host  all   postgres   192.168.100.21/32  md5

User for replication is 'replicate'. On the master, I have granted database access to 'replicate'user and created the publication.

I have also done a schema dump from Master to Slave using pg_dump.

Have I missed anything here?

Comment: Added to the pg_hba.conf: host database replicate 192.168.100.21/32 md5 but still getting the same error .

Answer (score 3):

> host replication replicate 192.168.100.22/32 md5

Logical replication needs to connect to an actual database.  The special name 'replication' is only used for physical replication, not logical replication.